# Center div in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I used `<div style="width: 742px; margin: 0px auto; ">` to center the container `div`.

In the browser it works, but when I open it in Microsoft Outlook it's not in the center.

I also used `!important` on the `margin` because I thought it took precedence over the CSS.

How do I center a `div` in the browser and email?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
<div align="center">

your code 

</div>
```

Only for Outlook

Comment: When it comes to writing HTML for emails you're best off referring to an HTML book from 1997.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with a `<div>` element. I had to use `<table>` instead.

Answer (score 7):

For emailing in general it is better to do use html attributes and deprecated tags instead of their CSS equivalents because some messaging systems ignore inline styles.

For example, instead of:

```
<div style="width: 742px; margin: 0px auto; ">...
```

You can use:

```
<body align="center"><table align="center" width="742">...
```

Or

```
<div align="center">...
```

Example 2, instead of:

```
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif;">My text</p>
```

You can do:

```
<font face="Arial" size="4">My text</font>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm using this also now and I fixed some other problems this way to!

Answer (score 1):

A good reflex is to go on the official Microsoft Documentation Network: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx

Here you can see that the best method is to use.. another thing than a div element.

Use a table, it allow the maximum of css control.