# Center HTML in OUTLOOK not working

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, outlook, center

I have spent all day reviewing fixes for my issue. My HTML looks great on all email clients except Outlook, by which the layout will not center in the preview. I've tried the `<center>` tag and fixing the `.ExternalClass` but nothing works. Can anyone help?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
<meta content="width=mobile-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-     scalable=no" name="viewport">
<meta content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>IAED ACE WEBSITE</title>
<style href="">a {text-decoration: none} </style>
<style type="text/css">
.mobile {
max-width:700px !important;
}
/**This is to overwrite Outlook.com’s Embedded CSS************/
table {
border-collapse:separate;
}
a, a:link, a:visited {
text-decoration: none; color: #2a8acc;
} 
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
h2,h2 a,h2 a:visited,h3,h3 a,h3 a:visited,h4,h5,h6,.t_cht {
color:#000 !important;
}
.ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td {
line-height: 100%;
}
/**This is to center your email in Outlook.com************/
.ExternalClass {
width: 100%;
}         

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     .mobile {width: 95% !important; font-size:1.1em; border-collapse: collapse; display:block; margin:0 auto; padding-bottom:15px;}
     .hide {display:none;}
     .btn_bg { width:50%; margin: 0 auto !important; font-size:1.0em; }
      }
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
     .mobile {width: 95% !important; font-size:1.1em; border-collapse: collapse; display:block; margin:0 auto; padding-bottom:15px;}
     .hide {display:none;}
     .btn_bg { width:50%; margin: 0 auto !important; font-size:1.0em;}
      } 

@media only screen and (max-width: 667px) {
     .mobile {width: 95% !important; font-size:1.1em; border-collaps: collapse; display:block; margin:0 auto; padding-bottom:15px;}
     .hide {display:none;}
     .btn_bg { width:50%; margin: 0 auto !important; font-size:1.0em;}
      }  

@media only screen and (max-width: 730px) {
     .mobile {width: 95% !important; font-size:1.1em; border-collapse: collapse; display:block; margin:0 auto; padding-bottom:15px;}
     .hide {display:none;}
     .btn_bg { width:50%; margin: 0 auto !important; font-size:1.0em; }
      } 
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#EFEFEF" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<!-- SPACE-->

<table bgcolor="#EFEFEF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=
"height:15px; background-color:#efefef; width:100%;" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--end of space-->
<!-- HIDDEN PREHEADER -->


<div style=
"display: none; font-size: 1px; color:#333333; line-height: 1px; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all;">
IAED ACE WEBSITE
</div>
<!--BEGIN OUTTER CONTAINTER-->


<table bgcolor="#EFEFEF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=
"background-color:#efefef;" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--BEGIN NAV-->


            <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding=
            "0" cellspacing="0" style=
            "background-color:#ffffff; width:700; margin:0 auto; border:thin solid #E8E8E8; color:#2a8acc;"
            width="700">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="line-height:15px; height:15px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>

                    <td width="35%">
                        <a href="http://www.emergencydispatch.org/" style=
                        "color:#2a8acc; text-decoration:underline;" target=
                        "_blank"><img src=
                        "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/iaed-logo-200w.png"></a>
                    </td>

                    <td align="left" valign="bottom" width="23%">
                    <span style=
                    "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2a8acc; text-align:left; font-size:18px;">
                    <a href="http://www.emergencydispatch.org/" style=
                    "color:#2a8acc; text-decoration:underline;" target=
                    "_blank">ABOUT IAED</a></span>
                    </td>

                    <td valign="bottom" width="20%"><span style=
                    "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2a8acc; text-align:left; font-size:18px;">
                    <a href="https://accreditation.emergencydispatch.org/"
                    style="color:#2a8acc; text-decoration:underline;"
                    target="_blank">WHY ACE</a></span>
                    </td>

                    <td valign="bottom" width="30%">
                        <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA -->


                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="30px">
                                    <a href=
                                    "https://www.facebook.com/InternationalAcademiesofEmergencyDispatch"
                                    style=
                                    "border:none; text-decoration:none;"
                                    target="_blank"><img src=
                                    "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/facebook-logo-round.png"></a>
                                </td>

                                <td width="30px">
                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/TheIAED"
                                    style=
                                    "border:none; text-decoration:none;"
                                    target="_blank"><img src=
                                    "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/Twitter-round-color.png"></a>
                                </td>

                                <td width="30px">
                                    <a href=
                                    "https://www.linkedin.com/company/international-academies-of-emergency-dispatch"
                                    style=
                                    "border:none; text-decoration:none;"
                                    target="_blank"><img src=
                                    "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/linkedin-round.png"></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="line-height:15px; height:15px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--END NAV-->
            <!--BEGIN BANNER -->


            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing=
            "0" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:700; margin:0 auto;"
            width="700px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href=
                        "https://accreditation.emergencydispatch.org/"
                        style="border:none;" target="_blank"><img class=
                        "mobile" src=
                        "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/banner-iaed.png"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--END BANNER -->
            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->


            <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0"
            cellspacing="0" style=
            "background-color:#ffffff; width:700; margin:0 auto; border-bottom:thin solid #E8E8E8;"
            width="700px">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="line-height:15px; height:15px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="3"><span style=
                    "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:24px; font-weight:800;">
                    FEATURES</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style=
                    "line-height:15px; height:15px; border-bottom:thin solid #E8E8E8;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="line-height:15px; height:15px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="25%"><img src=
                    "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/user-friendly.png">
                    </td>

                    <td width="70%">
                        <span style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:18px; font-weight:500;">
                        User-friendly</span>

                        <ul style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:14px;">
                        <li>Simple-to-use instructions for providing
                        information and uploading documents help you
                        complete the 20 Points requirements</li>


                            <li>Demo videos help guide you through various
                            facets of the application process</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>

                    <td width="3%">
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="line-height:15px; height:15px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="25%"><img src=
                    "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/cloud-icon.png">
                    </td>

                    <td width="70%">
                        <span style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:18px; font-weight:500;">
                        Upload everything—no more binders!</span>

                        <ul style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:14px;">
                        <li>Our easy and convenient upload process means
                        you can electronically upload required application
                        documents to the IAED’s secure servers 24/7</li>


                            <li>No more shipping heavy binders</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>

                    <td width="3%">
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="line-height:15px; height:15px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="25%"><img src=
                    "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/progress-icon.png">
                    </td>

                    <td width="70%">
                        <span style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:18px; font-weight:500;">
                        Progress bars</span>

                        <ul style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:14px;">
                        <li>You can track your ACE application progress for
                        each of the 20 Points achieving also your overall
                        progress and deadlines toward ACE</li>


                            <li>Uploading documents is made easy with a
                            progress bar that lets you know when your
                            upload is complete</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>

                    <td width="3%">
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="line-height:15px; height:15px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="25%"><img src=
                    "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/sync-icon.png">
                    </td>

                    <td width="70%">
                        <span style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:18px; font-weight:500;">
                        Sync your information</span>

                        <ul style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:14px;">
                        <li>The online ACE application system automatically
                        synchronizes 20 Points application tasks completed
                        during your communication center’s implementation
                        process</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>

                    <td width="3%">
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="line-height:15px; height:15px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="25%"><img src=
                    "https://www.emergencydispatch.org/vrc/iaed/2016/email/images/credit-icon.png">
                    </td>

                    <td width="70%">
                        <span style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:18px; font-weight:500;">
                        Re-accreditation ready</span>

                        <ul style=
                        "font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; text-align:left; font-size:14px;">
                        <li>You can refer to online documents previously
                        submitted by your agency for ACE or Re-ACE
                        requirements</li>


                            <li>Re-accreditation is a snap with the online
                            ACE application process</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="line-height:15px; height:15px;">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- END OF OUTTER CONTAINTER -->
</body></html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center div in Microsoft Outlook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137536/center-div-in-microsoft-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using adding `align="center"` to the "outer container" `<table />` and header `<div />`?

Comment: Yes, I tinkered with it in various positions including the ones you have suggested with negative results. I appreciate your time.